# I have one server that I want to put in a datacenter

Tags: rack, colocation

I only have one server. I don't need a whole rack. What's an economical option for this?

Is there any way to sublet part of a rack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many colocation facilities will offer you rack space "by the U" (one rack-unit space) increments or in 1/4 rack or 1/2 rack amounts. You should easily be able to find what you want.

Comment: If your google sauce is weak, try "server colo".

Comment: That was mostly the problem: "single server colo"